# How can I change the order of an xsl for-each?

Tags: xslt

I need to change the order in which my for-each is executed only if some conditions are met.

Here is what my XML looks like :

```
<OptionList>
    <Option name="My First Option" />
    <Option name="My Second Option" />
</OptionList>
```

However, in some case, my XML can be like this :

```
<OptionList>
    <Option />
    <Option name="My Second Option" />
</OptionList>
```

In my XSL, I'm doing a for-each like this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="//OptionList/Option">
    {...}
</xsl:for-each>
```

I know I can change orders of Option nodes using this line in my for-each :

```
<xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending" />
```

The problem is that I want my order to be descending only when my first Option node is empty and doesn't have the name attribute. Otherwise, I want to keep the default ascending order.

Any input on how I can acheive that? So far, everything I tried ended up with "Variable out of scope" or invalid use of xpath functions.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete and natural solution.

Comment: Would it be possible for the person who down voted this question (5 years and a half after it's been posted and answered) to explain himself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a hack to change the sort order based on a condition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
    <xsl:for-each select="//OptionList/Option">
      <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending"
        select="position()*(-2*number(not(//OptionList/Option[1]/@name))+1)"/>

      <option>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </option>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </result>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The hack is that `number((true())` returns 1 and `number(false())` returns 0. As a consequence, the expression

```
-2 * number(not(//OptionList/Option[1]/@name)) + 1
```

evaluates to `1` if the first `option` element has a `name` attribute and to `-1` otherwise. This is used as a factor to reverse the sort order.

Comment: +1 from me, because this is almost the exact solution I independently came to minutes ago. :)

Comment: +1 for reverse calculation. But the path is wrong. Inside the `xsl:sort/@select` the context node is every `Option` element, so the relative path should be `../Option[1]/@name`. Also, I think you should say that this can be done (more verbose) with `xsl:choose`, and that would be the rigth choise if the condition (wich it's been evaluated for every node) became ineficient.

Comment: I'm not an expert in xsl but this one seems to work best. In the end, it would be easier if it was possible to put a sort in a if! Or have the sort done directly in the xml. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**The order of producing the wanted output can be easily specified with `<xsl:sort>`:**

This is natural and easy and involves almost no hacks.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOrder" select=
   "2*boolean(/*/Option[1]/@name)-1"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:for-each select="Option">
       <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="$vOrder* position()"/>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed on the this XML document**:

```
<OptionList>
    <Option name="My First Option" />
    <Option name="My Second Option" />
    <Option name="My Third Option" />
</OptionList>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<OptionList>
   <Option name="My First Option"/>
   <Option name="My Second Option"/>
   <Option name="My Third Option"/>
</OptionList>
```

**When the same transformation is now performed on this XML document**:

```
<OptionList>
    <Option />
    <Option name="My Second Option" />
    <Option name="My Third Option" />
</OptionList>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced again**:

```
<OptionList>
   <Option name="My Third Option"/>
   <Option name="My Second Option"/>
   <Option/>
</OptionList>
```

**Explanation**: The variable `$vOrder` is defined in such a way, that it is `-1` iff the first `Option` element has no `name` attribute and it is `+1` if the first `Option` element has a `name` attribute. Here we use the fact that `false()` is converted automatically to `0` and `true()` to `1`.

We also use the fact that when the sign of each number in sequence of increasing positive numbers (the positions) is reversed, the order of the new sequence becomes decreasing.

Comment: This solution will not reverse the sort order of the option list, it will just put any empty option nodes at the end of the list. I read the question differently, I understood that the entire list should be reversed in case the first option element does not have a name attribute. Of course, if the list only has two items the result would be the same.

Comment: @0xA3: Thank you for alerting me to this. I spent ten minutes to solve the new problem, saved it and ... saw that it is almost exact copy of yours... :(. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the first option has the name node or not

```
<xsl:if test="Option/[position()=1]/@name">sort here</xsl:test>
```

Comment: Note that an `xsl:sort` node may not be contained in an `xsl:if` node.